# How to add navigationController to an already made tabbar based app?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have made a tabBarController application with 3 pages. Now I want to add navigation controller into the same.

The application has following classes and

```
(1) appDelegate.h, appDelegate.m
(2) first.h, first.m, first.xib
(3) second.h, second.m, second.xib
(4) third.h, third.m, third.xib
(5) MainWindow.xib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is simple. Just take one UINavigation Controller as you took UItabBarController. Whenever you want to add the Navigation Controller just assign it to mainWindow and from there you can come back to your tabBarController by just adding it to the mainWindow.

When you want to remove from tabBarController to the navigation controller then use the following code.

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

And When you want to remove from navigation controller to the tabBarController then use the following code.

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Let me know if you have any more question?

Comment: If you need any more help then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `first.h` as `navigationController` and assign that into the tabcontroller as one of the viewcontroller